# CORDA: How do I get all vault and their states that the peers interchanged in the corda network?

Tags: corda

I downloaded and ran the cordapp-example and then I sent transactions from the peers. When I inspected h2 database of all nodes I noted that the notary service doesn't have anything transaction in its database.

The main idea will be that the notary will generate transactions for each peer in the network as result of the interactions between peers.

How is it possible that notary doesn't save the transactions? What am I doing wrong?

Notary configuration file:

```
{
    "activeMQServer" : {
        "bridge" : {
            "maxRetryIntervalMin" : 3,
            "retryIntervalMs" : 5000,
            "retryIntervalMultiplier" : 1.5
        }
    },
    "baseDirectory" : "[PATH]",
    "dataSourceProperties" : {
        "dataSource.password" : "",
        "dataSource.url" : "jdbc:h2:file:[PATH]/Notary/persistence;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;WRITE_DELAY=100;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=0",
        "dataSource.user" : "sa",
        "dataSourceClassName" : "org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
    },
    "database" : {
        "exportHibernateJMXStatistics" : "false",
        "transactionIsolationLevel" : "REPEATABLE_READ"
    },
    "devMode" : true,
    "emailAddress" : "admin@company.com",
    "exportJMXto" : "http",
    "h2port" : 0,
    "keyStorePassword" : "trustpass",
    "myLegalName" : "O=Notary, L=Uruguay, C=UY",
    "notary" : {
        "custom" : false,
        "validating" : true
    },
    "p2pAddress" : "[IP]:10003",
    "rpcSettings" : {
        "address" : "localhost:10004",    
        "adminAddress" : "localhost:10005",
        "standAloneBroker" : false,
        "useSsl" : false
    },
    "rpcUsers" : [
        {
            "password" : "default",   
            "permissions" : [
                "ALL"
            ],
            "username" : "default"
        }
    ],
    "trustStorePassword" : "trustpass",
    "useTestClock" : false,
    "verifierType" : "InMemory",
    "webAddress" : "localhost:10006"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several reasons why the notary doesn't see all the transactions:

1. The notary in the Example CorDapp is non-validating (see https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/build.gradle#L81). This means that it only prevents double-spends, and does not get to see or store the transaction contents

   - However, you have modified the notary to be validating in your example above
2. Notaries are only sent a transaction if the transaction has input states and/or a timestamp (there's no need for them to see it otherwise, so it improves performance)
3. The standard notary implementation doesn't record a transaction. It just records the transaction's history. This isn't a requirement, it's just have how `ValidatingNotaryFlow` is implemented

Comment: Where did you set the property? What did you set it to? If you change this property after bootstrapping the network, you'll have to re-bootstrap it.

Comment: I have re-bootstrapped my network many times and it doesn't work. I recently load cnf file. you should see above.

Comment: See my answer above - it's probably covered by one of those?